# ArrayCollection::forAll with recursion

Tags: php, symfony, recursion, doctrine, closures

Today I found weird behavior when using ArrayCollection::forAll method against an anonymous function with a recursion.

**Preconditions:**

I have a collection of `Post` entities. Each `Post` contains a collection of `SocialPost` entities.

**Aim**:

Set status for all Post and SocialPost entities to "pending".

**My solution:**

I thought that I could use pretty simple closure, like this:

```
    $setPending = function($_, StatusAwareInterface $post) use (&$setPending) {
        echo "func entry point reached\r\n";
        if ($post instanceof Post) {
            echo "This is post. SP Count: " . count($post->getSocialPosts()) . "\r\n";
            $post->getSocialPosts()->forAll($setPending);
            $status = Post::STATUS_PENDING;
        } else {
            echo "This is SP\r\n";
            $status = SocialPost::STATUS_PENDING;
        }

        $post->setStatus($status);
    };

    // $post contains 2 Post entities
    // Each Post entity contains 50+ SocialPost entities
    $posts->forAll($setPending);
```

**Result:**

But the output is very strange. It looks like forAll uses only the first item and then breaks:

```
func entry point reached
This is post. SP Count: 52
func entry point reached
This is SP
```

Does anybody sees the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's check  [`ArrayCollection` source](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/source-class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html#_forAll)

Doc says:

```
      * Applies the given predicate p to all elements of this collection,
      * returning true, if the predicate yields true for all elements.
```

This may be misleasing because what it doesn't say is that if predicate returns `false`, the whole function `forAll` return `false` **immediately**.
Let's take a look at the source:

```
public function forAll(Closure $p)
{
    foreach ($this->elements as $key => $element) {
        if ( ! $p($key, $element)) { // <-- here's null converted to false.
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Your function doesn't return anything, which is `null`. Going further, `null` is converted to `false`, what causes `forAll` method to break before completing iteration over your `ArrayCollection`.

As a solution you should add line

```
return true;
```

at the and of your anonymous function.

**Additional note**: `forAll` should be be understand as

> check if every element in collection matches the condition

and not

> do something for each element of collection

If you want to do this right, you should simply do `foreach` loop.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was using this method assuming it works exactly like  array_walk. Thank you.